# My stringvar of the entry does not work properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have following Problem:
I have a table in which I documented which label for which article is needed.
The needed label should be updated automaticly when the entry is changed.
I look in a dataframe for the article number and give back the neede lable as picture.

For some reason it works only one time, and only if I enter with copy and paste the right article number. after the first time always the exept value is set to my variable.

I also don't understand the meaning of the *args as input for my search_label function. But without it gave me as soon as I entered something in the entry field the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python_3.9.1\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1884, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: search_label() takes 0 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os
import tkinter.messagebox as tkmb



def display_img(img_src):
    global img
    img = Image.open(img_src)
    'size of the picture'
    width_hight = 180
    img = img.resize((width_hight, width_hight))
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    panel = tk.Label(root, image=img, bd=0)
    'place in the middle of the window'
    panel.place(x=width / 2 - width_hight / 2, y=row3)

def search_label(*args):

    try:
        artikel = entry_var.get()
        artikel = str(artikel).upper()
        print('entry= ', artikel)
        #Needed cols of Excelfile
        cols = ['Nr_','Reinigungsmittel']
        global df
        df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=cols)
        #For some reason there are always spaces at the end of the artikel in the dataframe
        #remove spaces
        df['Nr_'] = df['Nr_'].str.strip()
        df.to_csv('Reinigungsmittel.csv', sep= ";", encoding='utf-8-sig')
        df = df.set_index('Nr_')
        #filter the dataframe only for artikel number
        print('df:')
        print(df)
        #make entry capital letters

        df_reinigungsmittel = df.loc[[artikel]]
        #get only the cleanning article
        cleaning_article = str(df_reinigungsmittel.iloc[0][0])
        print('ergebnis:')

        print(cleaning_article)
        cleaning_article = str(cleaning_article).strip()
    except:
        cleaning_article = 'label search failed'
    evaluation(cleaning_article)

def evaluation(cleaning_article):
    print('input evaluation:',cleaning_article)
    if cleaning_article == 'CMETHANOL':
        cleaning_article = 'rot.png'
    elif cleaning_article == 'CPROPANOL2':
        cleaning_article = 'gruen.png'
    elif cleaning_article == 'CPROPANOL':
        cleaning_article = 'blau.png'
    else:
        cleaning_article = 'non.png'
    print(cleaning_article)
    display_img(cleaning_article)


#load dataframe when program is opend, so the dataframe doent' need to be loaded for each search
datasource = r'C:\Arbeit\scripte\Reinigungslabel\Reinigungslabel.xlsx'
datasource_csv = r'C:\Arbeit\scripte\Reinigungslabel\Reinigungsmittel.csv'
#df = pd.read_excel(datasource)
df = pd.read_csv(datasource_csv, sep =';')

# Window and layout settings
hight = 270
width = 250

column_space = 5
column1 = 10
width_column1 = width - 20

#start value of cleaning_article
cleaning_article = 'non.png'

hight_row = 30
space_row = 5
row1 = 10
row2 = row1 + hight_row + space_row
row3 = row2 + hight_row + space_row


root = tk.Tk()
entry_var = tk.StringVar()
entry_var.trace('w',search_label)

print(df)
root.title("Reinigungs Label V1.0")

# get screen width and height
# width of the screen
ws = root.winfo_screenwidth()
# height of the screen
hs = root.winfo_screenheight()

# calculate x and y coordinates for the Tk root window
x = ws - (1.05 * width)
y = 30
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, hight, x, y))
root.configure(bg='black', bd=0)
Canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=hight, width=width).place()

frame_artikel = tk.Frame(root, bg = 'black')
frame_artikel.place(x=column1, y=row1, width=width_column1, height=hight_row)

entry_artikel = tk.Entry(frame_artikel, textvariable=entry_var, font=20)
entry_artikel.focus()
entry_artikel.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you really need `global df`? Also can you elaborate more with an example

Comment: I am not sure I I need global df. I used it because I define df before the function search_label is called. What do you mean to elaborate more with an example? The creation of the df works fine. I had a button to run the function, and it worked perfectly. Then I wanted to add the StringVar to update the search result permanently. But this does not work. it runs after the second change in the exept mode of the search function

Comment: Yes, remove `try`/`except` and find out what error comes.

Comment: I did so and following error ocurrs:````Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python_3.9.1\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1884, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: search_label() takes 0 positional arguments but 3 were given````

Comment: Cannot reproduce the said error.  Is `def search_label():` is used in your original code instead?  Note that `*args` means that the function can accept *any number of arguments*.

Comment: Make sure you are posting the correct code as you are using here, you only use `search_label()` twice here, and those seems to be fine

Comment: I use exactly the code as posted. The error message only "has a problem" with the search_label function. I have the feeling, that my  ````entry_var.trace('w',search_label)```` causes the problem. Becaus if I remember right, the trace function gibves the arguments. But I don't know who to makke it work properly. I do not understand the difference between ````entry_var.trace('w',search_label)```` and ````entry_var.trace('w',search_label())````., but if I hand over no arguments than immediatly an error occurs. Can't insert its too long.

Comment: ````.... raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Index([''], dtype='object', name='Nr_')] are in the [index]" ....
````

Comment: I found the misstake. Since there is a loop the dataframe first set index to the column "Nr". After entering the second charater it added the col Nr_ again and caused an error. Why I also do not know, but now it works. I used an extra dataframe whre the index is set. Thank you all for your helping!